# Auto-scaling virtual machine on Azure: Day In & Day Out

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, azure-virtual-machine

I need to use VM on azure 12 hrs/day, shutdown at EOD & start next day again in morning.
I am using to use WASABi block for auto-scaling.

> What strategy should I use for optimal cost & reliability?

1. Do I need to delete the VM completely to stop getting billed when
   not in use?
2. Keep .vhd in azure storage & fire a new VM with attached disk ever
   day?

Answer (score 2):

[As of June 2013 you will no longer be billed for Stopped VMs](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2013/06/03/windows-azure-announcing-new-dev-test-offering-biztalk-services-ssl-support-with-web-sites-ad-improvements-per-minute-billing.aspx). Also, you're billed per-minute now as of then as well. You WILL be charged for the storage space of the VHD in Azure storage though, but that's quite literally pennies.